# Hibernate preserve lazy loading feature while converting entity class into VO

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, lazy-loading

I am developing application using spring and hibernate. I am using lazy loading. 
My hierarchy of layer is `controller>>Service>>Converter>>Repository`, where converter task is to convert the entity into VO. Suppose I have two entity as below: Parent class as:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Parent")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Parent {

private Integer id;
private List<Childrens> childrens;

@Override
@Id    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column( name="Parent_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, updatable = false )
public Integer getId() { return id; }
private void setId(Integer id){this.id=id};

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE }, mappedBy = "parent")
@Column(nullable = false)
public List<Children> getChildrens() { return childrens; }
public void setChildrens( List<Children> childrens) { this.childrens = childrens; }

}
```

And child class as:

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "Children")
 @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
 public class Children  {

  private Integer id;
  private Parent parent;

 @Override
 @Id    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
 @Column( name="Parent_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, updatable = false )
public Integer getId() { return id; }
private void setId(Integer id){this.id=id};

 @ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.EAGER )
 @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", nullable = false )
 public Parent getParent() { return parent; }
 public void setParent(Parent parent) {
   this.parent = parent;
 }
 }
```

Now I have ParentVO as:

```
 public class ParentVO {

private Integer id;
private List<ChildrenVO> childrensVO;

public Integer getId() { return id; }
private void setId(Integer id){this.id=id};

public List<ChildrenVO> getChildrensVO() { return childrensVO; }
public void setChildrensVO( List<ChildrenVO> childrensVO) { this.childrensVO = childrensVO; }

}
```

And ChildVO as:

```
  public class ChildrenVO  {

  private Integer id;
  private ParentVO parentVO;

  public Integer getId() { return id; }
  public void setId(Integer id){this.id=id;}

  public ParentVO getParentVO() { return parentVO; }
  public void setParentVO(ParentVO parentVO) {
   this.parentVO = parentVO;
  }
  }
```

Whenever I request service for Parent class, it first retrieves service from dao and converts Parent to ParentVO as:

```
public class ParentConverter {
public ParentVO getParentVOFromParent(Parent parent){
    ParentVO parentVO=new ParentVO();
    ChildrenConverter childrenConverter=new ChildrenConverter();
    parentVO.setChildrens(childrenConverter.getChildrensVOList(parent.getChildrens()));
    return parentVO;
}
}
```

Here, `parentVO.setChildrens(childrenConverter.getChildrensVOList(parent.getChildrens()));` calls list of children which makes it no longer lazy.

And ChildrenConverter as:

```
public class ChildrenConverter {

public ChildrenVO getChildrenVOFromChildren(Children children){
    ChildrenVO childrenVO=new ChildrenVO();
    childrenVO.setId(children.getId());

    return childrenVO;
}

public List<ChildrenVO> getChildrensVOList(List<Children> childrens){
    List<ChildrenVO> childrenVOs=new ArrayList<ChildrenVO>();
    for(Children child: childrens){
        childrenVOs.add(getChildrenVOFromChildren(child));
    }
    return childrenVOs;
}
```

}

In controller I am only use VO objects so, what I want is :

> When I request ParentVO from service, it must not convert Children
>   List into ChildrenVO List until and unless I call ParentVO's
>   getChildrensVO() method.

Now, it will preserve hiberate lazy loading feature.
Is there any way to achieve this feature?

Comment: If you know when you are going to call childrens you can make 2 methods one which gives you only parent and one which gives you parent with childs...

Comment: Okay, but I want to achieve it from a single method. Is there a way.

Comment: you can use Hibernate.initialize(proxy); but I am not sure it will work... proxy object is parent.getChildrens()